While Capture Order on PayPal Geting PayPalSDKError missing HTTP response data
onApproveOrderFailure: com.paypal.android.corepayments.PayPalSDKError: Error: 3 - Description: An error occurred due to missing HTTP response data. Contact developer.paypal.com/support.
paypal sandbox dashboard
I will try this Code, token and order create is successfully but when listen ApproverOrderREsponse then got an error

private fun cardCheckoutTapped(cardRequest: CardRequest) {
        val result = cardClient.approveOrder(this, cardRequest)
        Log.i(TAG, "cardCheckoutTapped: $result")
    }

    private fun setupCardClient() {
        val config = CoreConfig(CLIENT_ID, environment = Environment.SANDBOX)
        cardClient = CardClient(this, config)
        cardClient.approveOrderListener = this
    }

    override fun onApproveOrderCanceled() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onApproveOrderCanceled: ")
    }

    override fun onApproveOrderFailure(error: PayPalSDKError) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onApproveOrderFailure: $error")
    }

    override fun onApproveOrderSuccess(result: CardResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onApproveOrderSuccess: $result")
        payPalViewModel.captureOrder(token, orderId)
    }

    override fun onApproveOrderThreeDSecureDidFinish() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onApproveOrderThreeDSecureDidFinish: ")
    }

    override fun onApproveOrderThreeDSecureWillLaunch() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onApproveOrderThreeDSecureWillLaunch: ")
    }

